# How can I create a new component on firing any event using Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Say, I am showing some posts that I got from an ajax response. Now I want to add the option to edit any particular post on clicking some button. I guess, I could do it using ***v-show***, where I will attach a form component or something with every single post and when the user clicks the edit button I will hide the post div and show the form with post's body and title and again on clicking save I could hide the form, send a request to the server to update the post then show it again.

Now my question is, is it doable without attaching and hiding anything in the first place? Because, how many times will I get users wanting to edit their posts? I want to call a function or something else with the post on some button click which will return a component with one or two text fields that have post data as their value.

Is it even possible using Vue?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to save on the additional `html` which would be present in the `DOM` per `comment-component` if you add `edit-comment-component`? also without using `v-show`. is `v-if` off the list too? because that would do the trick.

Comment: I do not have any issue with `v-show` or `v-if`, I just do not want to attach and then hide that `edit-comment-component`. On some event, I do want to hide the post but load `edit-comment-component`rather making it visible by changing some boolean variable.

Comment: I am just learning JS and JS Frameworks. In fact, Vue is my first JS framework that I started last week. So, things I am asking for might not make any senses. If that's the case, I am extremely sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: The things that come to my mind on that are: how would you style that? The `v-if` `v-show` would help you in maintaining the `edit-comment-component` in the document flow. Dynamically creating a component can work out too, but now that you say 'load' do you mean async loading the component?

Comment: I do not have much knowledge about 'async' loading. I think what I want is somewhat similar to Jquery's _append/html_ functions functionality. Instead of an HTML tag, I just want a Vue component.

Comment: `Vuejs` and `jQuery` work quite differently. `jQuery` directly manipulates the `DOM` which is slower than what modern web frameworks do instead, they modify a [virtual dom](https://www.accelebrate.com/blog/the-real-benefits-of-the-virtual-dom-in-react-js/). So the optimization you are thinking of might not be quite worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You can append a component to another this way:

```
// the parent component
const CommentComponent = new Vue({
  template: '<div>...</div>'
})

// the child component
const EditCommentComponent = Vue.extend({
  template: '<div> child </div>'
})

CommentComponent.$addChild({}, EditCommentComponent).$mount().$appendTo(CommentComponent.$el)
```

If you wish to do this within the parent component, you can do this by replacing `a` with `this`.

[- Source](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/659)

Although as I have inferred from the comments, this would not be the most appropriate way to handle your case.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution.

Comment: Btw, What would be your suggestion? I think I have to stick with v-if and v-else.

Comment: I'd suggest that too. `v-if` won't hurt your use case.